# Dataview webpart to display data from multiple list across site collection in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dataviewwebpart

I have two site collections named SiteColl1 and SiteColl2.

SiteColl1 contains List1.

SiteColl2 contains List2.

Now I want to display data from both lists [List1 and List2] in Dataview Webpart.
My Dataview webpart is placed in SiteColl1.

Is it possible to do the same? 
If YES, please suggest!!!!

Cheers!!!

Ketan

Answer (score 0):

you can not display data from different lists across site collection.
^^ WRONG

Learn sharepoint.  Dataview webparts, or content query webpartss will pull data from multiple lists in multiple locations across a site collection.

Comment: This is a none-answer.